# Mysql Maximum mark and student name

Tags: mysql, max

I need to a get the maximum mark of each subject,that student name in a table. There are six subjects. Toppers name and mark from each subjects

**SELECT DISTINCT name, MAX(evs) FROM eee2sem where(SELECT MAX(evs));**

This can be used to fetch only one subject result. Not overall maximum mark and the students Name, I need 6 results. Actually I need the maximum mark and the (mark holder) student name form every subject..

```
             Name | Sub1 |sub2  | sub3 | sub4
             ----------------------------------
             AAA  |  90  |   92 | 85   |  90
             BBB  |  82  |   96 | 89   |  98
```

Comment: Can you show how your table(s) are structured?

Comment: This is the table structure. I nee the toppers name and mark of each subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a answer,

SELECT name, sub1 FROM table name WHERE sub1 = (SELECT MAX (sub1) FROM table name) UNION SELECT name, sub2 FROM table name WHERE sub2 = (SELECT MAX (sub2) FROM table name) UNION SELECT name, sub3 FROM table name WHERE sub3 = (SELECT MAX (sub3) FROM table name) UNION SELECT name, sub4 FROM table name WHERE sub4 = (SELECT MAX (sub4);